# Impossible to hover on the img element, unable to rotate an element when img is hovered

Tags: html, css, transform, transition

Here is  the code **[jsfidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/randrini/2gbcy1Lj/16/)** code .

This needs a little explaination.
What I want is to rotate the 2 elements `.profile__photo--border-1` and `.profile__photo--border-2` (with the blueish border) when I hover the image `.profile__avatar`.

The `.profile__avatar` should **not** transform at all, only the 2 `div` elements around it with the blueish border **should rotate**.

Code snippet:

```
  <div class="profile__photo">
    <div class="profile__photo--border-1"></div>
    <div class="profile__photo--border-2"></div>
    <img class="profile__avatar" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/08/09/17/avatar-1577909_960_720.png" alt="profile photo">
</div>
```

The CSS is here, just a snippet though

```
img.profile__avatar {
  ---
  z-index: 20;  // Doesnt work ..

  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer; // Can't hover, the  image is always behind the 2 borders element

  }
  /* Trying with border-1, border-2 should be the same but -360deg rotate */

  &:hover .profile__photo--border-1 {
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you using scss?

Comment: Yes it is  scss.

Comment: Your selector is simply nonsense - you don’t have an element with the class `profile__photo--border-1` _inside_ the `img.profile__avatar` element. CSS can not select upwards or to the left in the DOM - this can only work if you start by putting the image element before the two border-divs in the DOM.

Comment: Can you give me  the corrected piece of code?  I still can't hover on the image.

Comment: Start with `pointer-events: none;` for the border-divs, so that the mouse cursor can “pass through” them ...

Comment: Wow! Finally I got it! Thank you @CBroe, Damn, that was hard for me solve. Never heard of the `pointer-events` property, I'm  a newbie anyway.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your have element over your image so to make them work you can remove them and add a transition

https://jsfiddle.net/Laavz8br/

```
...
transition: transform 1s ease-in;
...
```

Comment: I want to rotate the 2 div elements with blue border when I  hover  on the  image element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. You are rotating it 360 degrees. This code will rotate the image 180 degrees.

```css
.profile__avatar:hover {
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="profile__photo">
<div class="profile__photo--border-1"></div>
<div class="profile__photo--border-2"></div>
<img class="profile__avatar" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/08/09/17/avatar-1577909_960_720.png" alt="profile photo">
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but the  whole code is  in  the jsfiddle link. Added clearer description.